# Points on a map with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, point

I have a geoJSON of zip code centroid points that I am plotting on a D3.js map. I can get them to display but I am unable to adjust the size of the points. I was assuming that .attr("r", 1) would be doing that but I must be missing something.

```
        d3.json("ZipPoints.json", function (zipPoints) {
            svg.selectAll("g")
               .data(zipPoints.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path)
               .attr("r", 1)
               .style("fill", "red");
         });
```

EDIT:

```
        d3.json("ZipPoints.json", function (zipPoints) {
            points.selectAll("circle")
               .data(zipPoints.features)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("r", 1.5)
               .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                   return "translate(" + projection(zipPoints.features[i].geometry.coordinates) + ")";
                })
               .style("fill", "red")
               .classed("point", true);     
        });
```

Comment: why do you append "path" elements and not circles?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done this before. Is that what I should be doing? I changed "path" to "circle" and my points don't render.

Comment: It looks like you have the "points" actually defined as paths in your GeoJSON. In that case the proper way to do it would be to modify the GeoJSON to increase the size of the markers, although you could hack it by increasing the stroke width.

Comment: How do I know if the points are defined as paths in the GeoJSON? the "type" is "FeatureCollection" and the "geometry" "type" is "Point"

Comment: what Lars suggested was to use the .attr("stroke-width", //enter a size you want); to set the width of the stroke of the points, to increase their appereance

Comment: I understood that. However, I don't want the points to be larger I want them to be smaller. That's why I was attempting  .attr("r", 1). I tested this option ( .attr("stroke-width", //enter a size you want)) just to see if I could get the points to change size at all, and I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
var pins = svg.append("g");
d3.json("ZipPoints.json", function(zipPoints) {
    pins.selectAll("circle")
        .data(zipPoints.features)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .classed("pin", true);
});
```

You may need transformation on these points to render them correctly (I guess).
In that case you could use the following bit of code. (The transformation function I used was required to plot data that had lat, long information on a map built using a specific projection).

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    /*whatever transformation that needs to be done*/
    return "translate(" + projection([ d.lon, d.lat ]) + ")";
})
```